# How to know device autorotation is enabled or disabled in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a flutter app, and I'm using a youtube plugin to display a video. To implement my logic, I need to track whether auto-rotation is enabled or disabled on the phone. How can I do that? Please, help